# Automate "Send me a copy of email I send to a group" via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, outlook-web-app

Referenced MS Article:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/i-m-not-receiving-a-copy-of-messages-i-send-to-a-group-in-my-inbox-07567cda-f5ce-4e52-b278-4c63dfdd6617

I am looking for any possibilities to globally update the setting found in the referenced link above.

I've looked through every admin portal and potential PS references with no luck.

Comment: Why are you not just using Exchange routing rules for your use case vs trying to script this? [***'Exchange routing rule send a copy'***](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27exchange+routing+rule+send+a+copy%27&t=h_&ia=web)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this is a mailbox message configuration item. I'm using the `ExchangeOnlineManagement` module here, but it should be the same for other versions:

```sh
Connect-ExchangeOnline

# To see the current setting:
Get-Mailbox user@domain.com | 
  Get-MailboxMessageConfiguration | 
  Select EchoGroupMessageBackToSubscribedSender
# True|False

# To set for multiple users, get the list of mailbox objects
$mailboxes = Get-Mailbox  ## Filter as needed, and check your -ResultSize too
# The Set command will take the whole list as input
$mailboxes | Where { -Not EchoGroupMessageBackToSubscribedSender } |
  Set-MailboxMessageConfiguration -EchoGroupMessageBackToSubscribedSender $true
```